# group array division

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

this code  http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/5MQ77/

```
     var flowShadeBigArray =[] ;
          var x = [7, 411, 780]
          var y = [286, 712, 1058]

        for( var i = 0 ; i< x.length;i++){

            for(var index = x[i]; index <= y[i] ; index++ ){

                 var temp = [] ; 

                temp.push(index) ; 
                flowShadeBigArray.push(temp); 


            }

        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(flowShadeBigArray));
```

generate the following array

```
 [[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14]................[1056],[1057],[1058]]
```

i want to create a three arrays inside flowShadeBigArray and have the `[x[i] ... y[i] ]`
grouped together:

example

```
[  [  [7]....[286] ] , [ [411]...[712] ] ,[ [780]...[1058] ] ]
```

NOTE i still need to keep each of these numbers as an array so i can use it an an index for something else

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the `temp` initialization to the first loop, before the second, and the `.push()` to the first loop after the second (or before, doesn't matter).

```
var flowShadeBigArray = [];
var x = [7, 411, 780]
var y = [286, 712, 1058]

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var temp = [];

    for (var index = x[i]; index <= y[i]; index++) {
        temp.push(index);
    }
    flowShadeBigArray.push(temp);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5MQ77/1/

If each individual number belongs in its own Array, then change this:

```
flowShadeBigArray.push(temp);
```

to this:

```
flowShadeBigArray.push([temp]);
```

Comment: @user1389491: You mean you want each individual number in its own Array? Then change this `temp.push(index);` to this `temp.push([index]);`

Comment: i see what you mean i didn't that you can do .push([])

Comment: @user1389491: Yep, it's perfectly fine to push an Array into an Array.

Comment: Thanks  you           cliffs'

Answer (score 0):

-edited

```
function range(from, to) {
    var arr = [];
    while (from <= to) {
         arr.push([i++]);
    }
    return arr;
}
var result = [];
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    result.push(range(x[i], y[i]));
}
```